# How to get pthread_attr_t of the main thread in c language?

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to get the pthread_attr_t of the main thread. Is there any function to achieve this ?

I have look for such function on some websites, for example, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html. But there seems
no.

Can anyone help? thanks!

Comment: Do you want a portable solution, or one for your OS?

Comment: @jxh A portable solution is better. If no, for mac is ok.

Comment: The values in a `pthread_attr_t` structure are used for *thread creation* attributes.  Some of the values can have no relevance after the thread has started, and would be irrelevant for the main thread anyway.  How would you even define a value for the main thread stack size, for example?  Would it be the current size or the maximum possible size?  [Linux `pthread_getattr_np()`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_getattr_np.c) just grabs a few attributes from the requested thread.  In general, if you want information about a thread, you get it directly.

Comment: (cont) For example, if you want to know a thread scheduling parameters, you can call [`pthread_getschedparam()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_getschedparam.html).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no simple way to do this, as you have seen.

Instead, you can check your implementation's documentation, which should specify the default or inherited attributes of a process' initial (`main()`) thread.  (For example, in POSIX, [the initial thread is joinable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228440/132382).)  You can also use the `pthread_get*` functions to interrogate the initial thread's attributes at run time, but of course you need to know *a priori* which attributes to look for, since your implementation may have nonstandard attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the family of functions `pthread_attr_getxx` but as I have been told in the comments, the function did not modify the struct. So it cannot be used. If I don´t find a solution in a while I will delete the comment

Comment: Is there a portable function? I'm using mac os, there is not  a `pthread_getattr_np` function in <pthread.h>...

Comment: I didn´t know you were using mac os. Ok, there seem to exist functions for every field of the attr object ( pthread_attr_get ). Maybe you can create a wrapper to get all the info.

Comment: `pthread_attr_init` seems to init a pthread_attr_t struct with all fields has default values. How can I get pthread_attr_t struct for the main thread? Does pthread_attr_t for main thread also has the default values?

Comment: For the most part. https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpthread/libpthread-454.120.2/src/pthread.c.auto.html

Comment: @mrd2242 ```pthread_attr_init``` initializes the struct to the default values. But as you can see in @jxh link every ```pthread_attr_get ``` function modifies one of the values of the struct. I´ll update the answer

Comment: "modifies one of the values of the struct" I don't see this in the code. Can you show the line where the struct is modified?

Comment: @n. m. You are right, it doesn´t modify the struct.

Comment: *Now the value stacksize of pattr is set to the value of the running thread*  No it's not.  The values of `pattr` in your example have nothing to do with the values from any running thread.

Answer (score 0):

| stuff you can do with pthread_attr | in a thread you can get that info with |
| --- | --- |
| pthread_attr_setaffinity_np | pthread_getaffinity_np |
| pthread_attr_setinheritsched | Thread already exists, you can get current sched. |
| pthread_attr_setschedparam | pthread_getschedparam |
| pthread_attr_setschedpolicy | pthread_getschedparam |
| pthread_attr_setscope | dunno |
| pthread_attr_setdetachstate | dunno |
| pthread_attr_setsigmask_np | pthread_sigmask |
| pthread_attr_setguardsize | On Linux, parse /proc/*/maps. |
| pthread_attr_setstack pthread_attr_setstackaddr pthread_attr_setstacksize | On Linux, parse /proc/*/maps like glibc does https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_getattr_np.c#L81 |

Note that in your program you can wrap calls to `pthread_attr` and `pthread_create` and store the information yourself.

> of the main thread

I would guess the main thread has scope PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM and surely is not detached.